# :rpc.call fails with global registered node alias

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have an Elixir project that globally registers a node using the Erlang global module:

```
:global.register_name(:my_node, self)
```

From another node in the cluster I can get the pid of the registered node using the global alias:

```
:global.whereis_name :my_node
```

However I'm unable to issue an rpc call using the global alias. The following fails:

```
:rpc.call(:my_node, Foo.Bar, :new, ["hello"])
>> {:badrpc, :nodedown}
```

I'm able to issue the rpc call if I use the full node name. The following works:

```
:rpc.call(:"mynode@127.0.0.1", Foo.Bar, :new, ["hello"])
```

Is it possible to use global aliases with rpc calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global registry is for registering processes. So when you call:

```
:global.register_name(:my_node, self)
```

You are registering the current process (given by `self`) globally.

There is no node name registering because their names are already available globally. So the last snippet in your post is the correct way of doing so.